# In a non archimedean complete algebraically closed field, some special root of unity has distance $1$ from $1$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}_v$ be a complete algebraically closed non archimedean field. Let $t$ be an integer such that $|t|=1$, and let $\zeta$ be a $t^{th}$ root of unity. I think $|1−\zeta|=1$, but I can not prove it.

Attempts: I wrongly asked it on mathoverflow, but someone pointed out that it is not suitable for that site. He guided me to consider the two cases $|1−\zeta|>1$ and $|1−\zeta|<1$, and then to use Ultra-metric inequality. It is very clear to me that $|1−\zeta|\leq1$ (because both of $1$ and $\zeta$ belongs to $\mathcal{O}_v$, so the same happens for $1−\zeta$, also we can conclude by Ultra-metric inequality). But I can not finish it, what is the contradiction assuming $|1−\zeta|<1$?

Comment: Your statement is not quite correct: the number $1$ fits the conditions and $|1 - 1| = 0$. Use the uniqueness in the lifting from Hensel's lemma: if $K$ is a field complete with respect to a non-arch. absolute value and $|t| = 1$ then the polynomial $x^t - 1$ has a *unique* root $r$ such that $|r - 1| < 1$.  Since $1$ is such a root, it's the only one fitting the inequality $|r - 1| < 1$.  Thus every other $t$th root of unity fits the condition $|\zeta-1| = 1$.

Comment: @KCd Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: You can also do it in a more formal way: as $|\zeta|=1$, for any $1 \leq s < t$, $|1-\zeta^s|\leq 1$. Thus, $|1-\zeta| \geq \left|\prod_{1 \leq s < t}{(1-\zeta^s)}\right|$. Now, the RHS is the absolute value of $P(1)$, where $P(x)=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}=\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}{x^i}$. So $|1-\zeta| \geq |P(1)|=|t|=1$, QED.

Comment: @Mindlack wow! That's perfect. Thanks for this nice idea.